# request param is affecting attribute with same name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, request

I recently started learning the spring framework. I am stuck in this code here. I don't understand how `@ReqestParam` festival and `@RequestParam` federal (`boolean` values) can affect that my Controller is not returning attributes with the same name but type List. If I in URL state that `federal=true` and `festival = false`, my controller will return only the federal list with holidays.

```
 @GetMapping("/holidays")
public String displayHolidays(@RequestParam(required = false) boolean festival,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) boolean federal,Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("festival",festival);
    model.addAttribute("federal",federal);
    List<Holiday> holidays = Arrays.asList(
            new Holiday(" Jan 1 ","New Year's Day", Holiday.Type.FESTIVAL),
            new Holiday(" Oct 31 ","Halloween", Holiday.Type.FESTIVAL),
            new Holiday(" Nov 24 ","Thanksgiving Day", Holiday.Type.FESTIVAL),
            new Holiday(" Dec 25 ","Christmas", Holiday.Type.FESTIVAL),
            new Holiday(" Jan 17 ","Martin Luther King Jr. Day", Holiday.Type.FEDERAL),
            new Holiday(" July 4 ","Independence Day", Holiday.Type.FEDERAL),
            new Holiday(" Sep 5 ","Labor Day", Holiday.Type.FEDERAL),
            new Holiday(" Nov 11 ","Veterans Day", Holiday.Type.FEDERAL)
    );
    Holiday.Type[] types = Holiday.Type.values();
    for (Holiday.Type type : types) {
        model.addAttribute(type.toString(),
                (holidays.stream().filter(holiday -> holiday.getType().equals(type)).collect(Collectors.toList())));
    }
    System.out.println(model.toString());
    return "holidays.html";
}
```

Comment: can you show me your entity?

Comment: add `Holiday` class, it might help determine problem